# Android Retrofit @Header and @Field use together?

Tags: android, retrofit

Android Retrofit @Header and @Field use together possible?

@Header is working fine but **it gives id as null.**
I tried id as integer but same.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/confirm-user-request")
Call<Confirm> confirmUserRequest(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
        @Field("id") String id);
```

Using only @Field is working fine.
I can both receive email and password correctly.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/login")
Call<Login> tryToLogin(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

Comment: yes you can use

Comment: Can you debug and make sure the value passed to "id" is not null

Comment: @mujeeb.omr okay. I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Headers({
   "Accept: application/json",
// "Content-Type: application/json", 
})
```

The issue was because of "Content-Type: application/json".
I removed it.
It is working okay.